# Trying to do left outer joins to two related tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

class Baz(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'baz'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(ForeignKey('foo.id'), nullable=True)
    foo = relationship('Foo', backref='bazes')
    bar_id = Column(ForeignKey('bar.id'), nullable=True)
    bar = relationship('Bar', backref='bazes')
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
```

So Baz has foreign keys back to Foo and Bar.

Say Foo has three rows with names a, b, and c. And say Bar has three rows with names x, y, and z.

I want to perform a query that gets me the number of rows in Baz for a given Foo and Bar, even if the answer is 0. Something like this for the return value:

```
('a', 'x', 12)
('a', 'y', 3)
('a', 'z', 0)
('b', 'x', 9)
('b', 'y', 0)
('b', 'z', 1)
('c', 'x', 3)
('c', 'y', 6)
('c', 'z', 2)
```

For a single related table, I understand how to do a subquery on Baz (grouped by Baz.foo_id) and then have a query on Foo that left outer joins with Baz. But for *two* related tables, I'm at a loss. Is it possible to do this query in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use subqueries for this purpose. Here is the SQL I would generate:

```
SELECT foo.name, bar.name, (SELECT COUNT('*') FROM baz WHERE baz.foo_id=foo.id AND baz.bar_id=bar.id) FROM foo, bar
```

An in SQLAlchemy:

```
count_query = session.query(func.count('*')).filter(Baz.foo_id==Foo.id).filter(Baz.bar_id==Bar.id).correlate(Bar).correlate(Foo).as_scalar()
query = session.query(Foo.name, Bar.name, count_query)
```

I am no expert concerning the performance of this query versus a query with cleverly combined OUTER JOINs, so I am not sure if this is any slower. I would have otherwise tried something like:

```
FROM foo LEFT OUTER JOIN baz ON foo.id=baz.foo_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN bar ON bar.id=baz.bar_id
```

I am not sure this yields what you need and right now I only have sqlite available which doesn't support `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` so I cannot test this. But I *have* verified tha the above query generates the result you want.

Comment: I didn't know about correlate--this is perfect. Thank you so much! As a side note, if I wanted several aggregate queries on Baz--the averages of three different fields on Baz, say--would I just make each a separate as_scalar subquery? Or is there a more elegant way to get them all simultaneously? Thanks again.